# What conditions I should met to call TForm's members from win32 thread?

Tags: c++, winapi, c++builder

I created a thread using CreateThread() with standard function prototype
`DWORD WINAPI func(LPVOID param);`

When I call TForm's members sometimes it crashes with access violation. 
I do not want use Embarcadero's TThread style functions, prefer to win32 std api.
What synchronize/other conditions I should met to successfully call TForm's or its descendants members?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Calling VCL methods in threads other than the main thread is not supported.

You need to find a way to keep all your VCL access in the main thread.  One commonly used technique is the `Synchronize()` method.  You could also send windows messages since they will always be marshalled across to the thread that owns the window.

I imagine that it's the same in C++ Builder as it is in Delphi, but in Delphi it is preferable to call `BeginThread()` rather than `CreateThread()`. `BeginThread()` is a lightweight wrapper of `CreateThread()` but the main thing it does for you is to set the `IsMultiThread` global variable.  If you do insist on calling `CreateThread()` then you must set `IsMultiThread` true first.

Comment: Thanks David, can you please show some C++ examples of using Synchronize() method. I am using C++ Builder (RAD Studio 2010)

Comment: @Sergey I don't use C++ Builder. I'm coming at this from knowledge of the VCL learnt through Delphi.

Comment: @Sergey: `Synchronize()` is a method of the `TThread` class, which you stated you did not want to use.  So you will have to use `SendMessage()` to send custom messages to the main thread instead.